# Google Chrome - Profile not loading

Tags: google-chrome, sync

Recently I tried to reset my google-chrome settings by deleting `~/.config/google-chrome` which I hoped would then sync with all the settings I have on my other computer.

Now, however, I can only see my bookmarks. I can't add any more bookmarks, and one add-on ( adblocker ) appears next to my address bar, but gives an error.

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
```

and then reinstalling and nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the output of `ls ~/.config/google-chrome`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either create a new browser user profile

Enter the following directory in the text field:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/
```

- Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens
  and rename it as "Backup default."
- Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is
  automatically created as you start using the browser.

Or create a new user

- Sign in to Chrome.
- In the upper right corner of the browser window, click the button for
  the current user. It may show that person's name, email, or an icon
  like this Sign in.
- Click Switch Person.
- At the bottom of the window, click Add Person. If the new person
  signs in to Chrome with a Google Account, he or she will see synced
  bookmarks, apps, extensions, and other browsing data on the computer
  and will be able to sync any future changes.

source https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en

Comment: Thank You! For future readers, I had a little trouble and I had to "remove" my google account about four times, each time also removing the Default directory until I was signed in to chrome as "You". Then it allowed me to sign in again and have all my settings synced.

Comment: @EricPower you are welcome friend

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to uninstall gnome-shell-integration with:

```
sudo apt-get purge chrome-gnome-shell
```